# Center a short text block that is align left

Tags: html, css, centering

It is easy to center a long text with margin 0 auto and control the distance with the margin or the padding.

But, Is it possible to center a text without knowing the width and if that text is align left ?

- Center a short text
- text alignt left
- I don't know the width

Here is the example to check: http://jsfiddle.net/j4Y3k/5/

CSS:

```
#long {
    margin:50px auto;
    text-align:left;
    padding: 0px 100px;
    background:white;
}

#short {
    margin:0px auto;
    text-align:left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="long">
long, long,long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, 
</div>

<div id="short"> 
short, short, short<br>
short, short, short, short, short, short<br>
short, short
</div>
```

Comment: `margin: 50px auto` is useless there if you don't have a fixed width

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand your example - can't you set the same padding on the `short` div? Failing that, set the same width on both of them.

Comment: I updated the question: Is it possible to center a text without knowing the width if that text is align left, ?

Comment: You are very welcome, and thank you for taking the time to frame your question in a clear and concise manner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it easily if you allow yourself to do the following:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="short">short, short, short
        <br>short, short, short, short, short, short
        <br>short, short</div>
</div>
```

and apply the following CSS:

```
.wrap {
    text-align: center;
}
#short {
    margin:0px;
    auto;
    text-align:left;
    outline: 1px dotted blue;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/GywRR/

The `inline-block` will shrink-to-wrap your content and still respond to the `text-align: center` property declared for the parent container.

**Why inline-block versus block**

`block`'s will use the maximum available width, usually the width of the parent container.  `inline-block` will shrink-to-fit (the term in the w3.org docs!), which usually gives you a width less than that of the parent container, which then allows the centering to work.

Comment: Great solution! Clear and simple. Thank you.

Comment: Just to understand: is there any special reason why does inline-block works and not display:block?

Comment: Good question: the answer is how the width is computed for the default case of `width: auto`.  `block`'s will use the maximum available width, usually the width of the parent container.  `inline-block` will shrink-to-fit (the term in the w3.org docs!), which usually gives you a width less than that of the parent container, which then allows the centering to work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a `width` when centering using "margin auto". Also you had a syntax error in your `margin` property;

```
#short {
    margin:50px auto;
    text-align:left;
    width:300px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j4Y3k/2/

You may think you've centered the long element, but this is just because its ran out of space, and the `100px` padding has forced the gaps on either side. You need to set `width` property on this too if you wish to truely center it.

Comment: that is the point: the only way to center a left align text is knowing the width?