# Line break caused by long words visually breaks the centering of paragraphs with left-aligned text

Tags: html, css

I am creating a centered paragraph with left-aligned text. In most cases, everything works very well. However, when there is a really long word at the end of the line which forces the text to break to the newline, it leaves a lot of white space at the end of the first line. This makes the whole paragraph look visually "uncentered" - leaning more towards the left side like shown in the code example (imagine gray background not being there).

I have tried to experiment with `inline-block` but unsuccessfuly so far. As I believe this could be a very nice riddle, I decided to share it here. Note: It is also not clear what text ends up inside the paragraph, so we need to think of a general solution (no hardcoded margins etc.). Words need to stay as they are, `break-word` is not appropriate for my scenario.

```css
.content {
  margin: auto;
  width: 400px;
}

p {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>
    At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio digducimusverylongword qui
  </p>
</div>
```

I tried to work with this discussion: [Center a short text block that is align left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189696/center-a-short-text-block-that-is-align-left). But it does not seem to be valid when the linebreak is automatic instead of an explicit `<br>` element.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon your i18n end goal, you could just define the `word-break` property:

```css
.content {
  margin: auto;
  width: 400px;
}

p {
  background-color: #eee;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>
    At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio digducimusverylongword qui
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not plausible for my scenario. The words need to stay intact. Still giving an upvote ;-). Can you think of a solution which takes this new condition into consideration?

Answer (score 1):

Although I realise it's probably not what you're looking for (and that [@BenM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58803341/930393) of using `word-break: break-all` is probably more appropriate)... another option is simply using `text-align:justify`...

```css
.content {
  margin: auto;
  width: 400px;
}

p {
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align:justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>
    At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio digducimusverylongword qui
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this is, as you noted, not what I am looking for. When the big missing space on the end of the line gets spread between words, it creates too much empty space between them by rule.

Comment: Although I couldn't get it to work (so I am not updating my answer) [according to this](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/hyphenate/) you should be able to use `hyphens`. Would be interested to know if you do get it working though